# Running Automation test in PhantomJS through Webdriver-IO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, webdriver-io

I have been trying to run my tests on phantomjs, directly through mocha, or wdio or gulp, But every time tests dies out with error of timeout. Though tests run perfectly on chrome and firefox, its just in phantomjs I get an error. I have installed phantom js globally and and in my project, but I am unable to get it work since last 2 days.

that's how I have done it the test

```
before( function (done) {
    driver = webdriverio.remote({ desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'phantomjs'
    } });

    driver.init(done);
});
```

Link to my project : https://github.com/anarwal/asg...

NOTE: I run tests on windows, that is where the problem is, they work fine on MAC

Comment: It could be anything. Try narrow down where the problem lies. Take screenshots and check which steps fail. The question as it currently stands cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a headless browser you need a selenium server running.

There is an very well explained example using javascript [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545).

Answer (score 0):

You may find Chimp.js useful as it easily allows you to use Chrome or FF locally but PhantomJS on the server. See: http://chimpjs.com/

Chimp.js works by "seamlessly integrating CucumberJS / Mocha, Selenium, WebdriverIO and Chai / Jasmine Expect to work in unison. It's designed to take away all the pain that comes with setting up these tools to play nicely together..." - Read more at: https://chimp.readme.io/docs